# What are all of the linux distros?

Tags: linux, distributions, 64bit

I am running Ubuntu currently, but I want to try other linux distros. I am not bored of Ubuntu, but I want to try as many Linux distros as I can. So if anyone knows of a Linux OS just post the name and if you want, you can post a link.

Comment: [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Check [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/)  .

Check this [graph](http://files.cyberciti.biz/uploads/tips/2007/06/44218-linuxdistrotimeline-7.2.png) also if you want to have a global view about some of those distributions ad the timeline.

Comment: Well that answered my question in one link, thanks

Comment: Is there an up to date version of the distros?

Answer (score 1):

I wont list all of them; but I'll list the two main distro types:

RedHat and Debian

RedHat has spawned CentOS (very popular server OS), Scientific Linux, and Fedora (of course there are others).

Debian has spawned Ubuntu which has spawned Mint and others.

There are completely different distro types as well such as Gentoo, Arch, and Slackware.